# Using Key object handle in PKCS#11

Tags: c, encryption, pkcs#11, hsm

I am trying to interact with HSM using PKCS#11 functions given by vendor.
I use below series of function to generate secret key, encrypt and decrypt data.
Below sequence works good.

1. `C_Initialize`
2. `C_OpenSession`
3. `C_Login`
4. `C_GenerateKey //3DES KEY`
5. `C_EncryptInit`
6. `C_Encrypt`
7. `C_DecryptInit`
8. `C_Decrypt`
9. `C_Logout`
10. `C_CloseSession`

My Questions:

1. After using C_Logout & C_CloseSession is there a way to reuse same KEY(generated earlier) again by logging back and opening session again with same login credentials?
2. When I use C_CreateObject does it create session object and destroy it on using C_CloseSession?

Comment: Once the key is generated, it is stored on the device and can be accessed by its properties (such as ID). Of course by logging in the second time you can find the object by its ID or other attributes and reuse it.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp If `CKA_TOKEN` is not set (and by default it is not set) then you won't find the object after closing the session(s).

Comment: Harsha, PKCS#11 and HSM are not tags that are very well monitored. Please use either [tag:cryptography] or [tag:encryption] when mentioning this subject.

Comment: @owlstead I stand corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Question**: After using C_Logout & C_CloseSession is there a way to reuse same KEY(generated earlier) again by logging back and opening session again with same login credentials?

Yes, just set `CKA_TOKEN` to `CK_TRUE` and provide a label using `CKA_LABEL` to search for it using `C_FindObjects`.

---

> **Question**: When I use C_CreateObject does it create session object and destroy it on using C_CloseSession?

Well, yes, according to the PKCS#11 specifications (v2.20, 10.4, Table 21):

> `CKA_TOKEN` is `CK_TRUE` if object is a token object; `CK_FALSE` if object is a session
>   object. Default is `CK_FALSE`.

---

Note that your token may not allow all possible attributes or attribute combinations to be set, and may have memory and other limitations.